# Можно ли QLineEdit сделать многострочным?

Tags: c++, qt

Можно ли QLineEdit сделать многострочным? Я имею ввиду чтобы там оставалась одна строка, нельзя было enter нажать, просто чтобы буквы отображались не в длину а как в QTextEdit, но на деле это была одна строка.

Comment: Если кратко, то у QLineEdit ничего такого нет... Окромя QPlainTextEdit'а ничего предложить не могу... осталось только придумать, как поаккуратней ограничиться одним абзацем...

Comment: Если все таки будете пытаться, попробуйте унаследоваться от QLineEdit и переписать ивенты.